# AmazonEC2 exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Why do I get this when trying to get the network interfaces ?

```
   com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: null (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: null)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1639)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.doInvoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:15651)
at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.invoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:15627)
at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.executeDescribeInstances(AmazonEC2Client.java:7621)
at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.describeInstances(AmazonEC2Client.java:7597)
at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.describeInstances(AmazonEC2Client.java:7633)
```

I am using below code for example. This is just a standalone code for testing.

```
AmazonEC2 amazonEC2 = getEC2Client();
    try {
        DescribeInstancesResult result = amazonEC2.describeInstances();
        for(Reservation reservation : result.getReservations()){
            System.out.println(reservation.getInstances());
        }

    }catch (AmazonEC2Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

protected static AmazonEC2 getEC2Client() {
    conf = new ClientConfiguration();
    conf.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
    conf.setSocketTimeout(20000);
    conf.setMaxErrorRetry(2);
    AmazonEC2 client;
    if (access_id == null && access_key == null) {
        client =  AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().withClientConfiguration(conf).withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("https://iam.amazonaws.com", "us-east-1"))
                .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false))
                .build();
    } else {
        client = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().withClientConfiguration(conf).withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("https://iam.amazonaws.com","us-east-1"))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(access_id, access_key)))
                .build();
    }
    return client;
}
```

I can access the list of Users in the same class but not the Describe* related stuff. Can someone please comment ?

Comment: Does your account have enough permissions for "Describe* related stuff"?

Comment: Also, please try to use `.withRegion(..)` and do not use `.withEndpointConfiguration(...)`. Perhaps you use incorrect endpoint definition.

Comment: Can you add this an answer please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `.withRegion(..)` and do not use `.withEndpointConfiguration(...)`. Perhaps you use incorrect endpoint definition.